# Setting brightness on Windows 10 using C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, monitor

I am trying to set the brightness on a Windows 10 machine. The display doesn't seem to support `setMonitorBrightness`, and `setDeviceGammaRamp` alters the gamma, white point etc, so I would try not to use it.

I am trying to get this to work using `IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS` control.  When I get the monitor handle using `CreateFile()`, I check if the handle is invalid and it is fine. But I get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (error 6) when I call `DeviceIoControl()` with `IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS`.

```
typedef struct _DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS {  
   UCHAR ucDisplayPolicy;  
   UCHAR ucACBrightness;  
   UCHAR ucDCBrightness;  
} DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, *PDISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS; 

DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS _displayBrightness;

_displayBrightness.ucDisplayPolicy = 0;
_displayBrightness.ucACBrightness = 0;  //for testing purposes
_displayBrightness.ucDCBrightness = 0;

DWORD ret = NULL;
OVERLAPPED olp;

DWORD nOutBufferSize = sizeof(_displayBrightness);
HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\LCD",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0, NULL);

if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    //Does not reach here
    return false;
}  

if (!DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, (DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS *)&_displayBrightness, nOutBufferSize, NULL, 0, &ret, &olp))
{
    // GetLastError() returns error code 6 - Invalid handle 
    return false;
}
```

Also, should I be using `CreateFile()` to get the monitor handle, or can I call `MonitorFromWindow(nullptr, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY)` instead?

Comment: `&olp` is a pointer to an uninitialized `OVERLAPPED` structure, that has a handle to an event object. I'd assume that that is the *invalid handle* the `DeviceIoControl` complains about. You don't need to pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure anyway, so simply pass `NULL`.

Comment: That was EXACTLY the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call

```
DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS,
                (DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS*)&_displayBrightness, nOutBufferSize, NULL, 0, &ret,
                &olp)
```

`&olp` points to an uninitialized [OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342.aspx) structure. This structure has a handle to an event object (*hEvent*), that holds a random value. This is the invalid handle the `DeviceIoControl` call complains about.

Since you aren't calling `CreateFile` with a `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag (which really wouldn't make sense for a display device anyway) you don't need to pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure at all. Simply pass `NULL`, and the call will succeed:

```
DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS,
                (DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS*)&_displayBrightness, nOutBufferSize, NULL, 0, &ret,
                NULL)
```