# How to power off or black screen monitor on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, monitor, ioctl

I am dealing with black screening like Teamviewer.

I want to power off monitor or make a completely black.

This method https://stackoverflow.com/a/713511/2469925 is useless for me. Because when mouse or keyboard in use monitor automatically opens back.

I found IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_OUTPUT_DEVICE_POWER_STATE but I guess it looks deprecated after XP. I think there is no usage currently.

Also I tried [Setting brightness on Windows 10 using C++ WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262619/setting-brightness-on-windows-10-using-c-winapi) this method with Teamviewer Monitor driver.(Teamviewer driver allow me to reach device)
I could get handle with Createfile but

DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS,
(DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS*)&_displayBrightness, nOutBufferSize, NULL, 0, &ret,
NULL)

always return 1 which is error/invalid function.

When I check my win10 settings also I could not find brightness settings. There is no such menu.

Any help is will be appreciated.

How can I do this with driver or driverless.

Comment: "*`DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS)` always return 1 which is error/invalid function*" - I assume you mean `DeviceIoControl()` returns `FALSE` and then `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`, is that right? In any case, what about simply displaying a full-screen black window?

Comment: You might get better responses if you asked about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the issues you have with getting your proposed solution to work. This is commonly referred to as the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Yes, exactly @RemyLebeau .I have tried more than 5 diifferent open source project in vb or c# also there was no proper application related this topic.